# wxPython get event ID

Tags: python, events, wxpython

I have some code, which binds a menu item to a method:

```
def getEventID(self, event):
    print id # how do I get id?

EVT_MENU(self, 123,  self.getEventID)
```

So basicly, I want my app to print "123" when the menu item with that ID is pressed. How would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just be able to use `event.GetId()` I believe.  You can also use `event.GetEventObject()` to get the widget that fired the event.

Comment: @Judge - Glad to hear it.  Make sure you accept the answer when you can to ensure you continue to get high quality answers from other users. :)