# Bind multiple wx.EVT_MENU to a same method?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, popupmenu

There're about 5-6 menu items in the right click popup, and binding them to separate methods seems clumsy since there's a good chunk of codes can be reused, is it possible to do things like this?

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.MenuClicked, id=self.menu1)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.MenuClicked, id=self.menu2)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.MenuClicked, id=self.menu3)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.MenuClicked, id=self.menu4)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.MenuClicked, id=self.menu5)

def MenuClicked(self, event):
    detect which menu being clicked
    assign specific values to several variables regarding the menu being clicked

    rest of the codes.
```

I noticed there's no `GetMenu()` available for `wx.EVT_MENU`, so basically how do you recognize which menu is being clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefere binding them to seperate methods but each to there own :)
You can use the GetId() method on the event and then compare it with your menu items.

```
def MenuClicked(self, event):
    id_selected = event.GetId()
```

Comment: Dude, did you actually try these codes yourself? `'CommandEvent' object has no attribute 'GetID'`, so `GetID()` won't work...

Comment: Yes Dude. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791676/wxpython-get-event-id,     http://zetcode.com/wxpython/events/

Comment: Oh my bad. I mistakenly upper-cased it in my code... Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this, but a standard and generic approach is to use [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html):

```
f = functools.partial(self.MenuClicked, my_id_1)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, f, id=self.menu1)
```

where `my_id_1` is some identifier, possibly self.menu1 if you like, and then elsewhere:

```
def MenuClicked(self, my_id, evt):
    print my_id
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I was wondering is there a way to get which menu is being clicked directly from `event` parameter?